# Angular Single Page Application How to Write Image

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a single page application that to write an image to a directory not in the server but in the client since in a SPA you store all the assets in the client. I have found tons of info in how to save an image in a server directory but not one discussing how to save it in the client.

My question is how do you write an image to the client directory?

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: What *"client directory"*? Do you mean on the user's machine?

Comment: Yes in the same directory I have all the assets of the application.

Comment: Your question doesn't exactly make sense.  Firstly, you don't "store all the assets in the client", and secondly, web apps running in a browser don't have access to the client computer's disk.  Please try and [edit] your question and clarify the exact scenario you are trying to solve.

Comment: That folder is on your webserver, and doesn't exist on the client side; they simply request resources in it from the server.